# How to fix the below mention error in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, playsound, gtts

1. context:- below is my code and It is showing error
   `"import speech_recognition as sr ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'"`

```
import os
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
def speak(text):
    tts= gTTS(text=text,lang="en")
    filename="voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

speak("hello tim")``
```

I am just making for speech recognition

Comment: have you run `pip install SpeechRecognition` or have you installed the SpeechRecognition package for your version of python ?

Comment: The duplicate might not solve your problem because you have provided no details whatsoever as to what the problem might be. If you can't find the answer and want this reopened, please [edit] your question to explain what exactly you have done to install the module, where, etc and provide the full traceback. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. A less generic title would be good, too; you won't gather many eyeballs with one which says basically "information is elsewehere in the post".